# What's the common way to layout a Django app with Buildout/djangorecipe?

Tags: django, buildout

I have a Django app that I've set up using Buildout laid out like so:

```
/workspace
  /bin
  /src
    /myproject
      settings.py
      /myapp
         views.py
         ...
  bootstrap.py
  buildout.cfg
  setup.py
```

The issue is that I'd like both `myproject.settings` and `myapp` on the python path. I need the `myproject.settings` on the path so djangorecipe can import it. And I'd like `myapp` on the path so that I don't have to write `import myproject.myapp` all the time.

For now I've got both `/workspace/src` and `/workspace/src/myproject` in the Python path, but this feels like a hack and practically makes me worried if there might be situations where `import some_module` might have confusing resolution patterns because I have two directories that are parent-child to each other.

So questions are:

Is there an accepted way to lay this out?

Is it actually bad to have a directory and one of its sub-directories in the path?

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem, on  `import some_module` importer will search in each folder specified at `sys.path` for  `some_module/__init__.py` and `some_module.py`. Same for `import myproject.some_module`, it will search for `myproject` module, then it will try to find in it `some_module` with same algorithm.

I'm using the same project structure.

Answer (score 0):

If your `buildout.cfg` includes `develop = .` and whatever egg your `setup.py` defines is included as a dependency for your buildout/parts then whatever code path your setup.py defines will be automatically added to sys.path.  Just make sure your `setup.py` includes `src` as a code directory.  One way to do this is with:

```
setup(name=...
...
      packages=find_packages('src'),
      package_dir = {'':'src'},
...
```